# Propel automatic form

Tags: php, forms, automation, propel

I'm just starting with Propel and for more rapid development I'm curious if there is anything like automatic forms. Something like default administration in Django.
I want to be able to output a form or to get all information I'll need. Even in the objects I didn't find all information which should be necessary to have everything for the form (name, type, length, related object, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Plain" Propel doesn't do this, but if you use it with a framework like [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/), you get what you need. Symfony is a better comparison to the Django stack, Propel is only the ORM-layer (there is another ORM-option for Symfony, [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), but I prefer Propel).

I also used [patForms](http://trac.php-tools.net/patForms) as a form layer in a custom CMS, because it has Propel bindings. But patForms isn't developed any more, so it would need extra work on your side to get it working.